# Отсортировать массив по возрастанию

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

Задание - "Создайте класс с именем student, содержащую поля: фамилия и инициалы, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов). Создать массив из десяти элементов такого типа, упорядочить записи по возрастанию среднего балла. Добавить возможность вывода фамилий и номеров групп студентов, имеющих оценки, равные только 4 или 5." В процессе выполнения застопорился на моменте, где надо упорядочить по возрастанию среднего балла, т.е. сам средний балл найден, а вот как отсортировать - без понятия, всё что ни пробовал - мимо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class student 
{
public:

    string fullname;
    int gnumber;
    int marks[5];

};

int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    const int size = 5;
    student arr[size];

    //ввод
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Введите фамилию и инициалы студента: ";
        cin >> arr[i].fullname;
        cout << "Введите номер группы: ";
        cin >> arr[i].gnumber;
        cout << "Успеваемость студента:\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << "Оценка " << j + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i].marks[j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    //сортировка

    double avg[size];
    double sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            sum += arr[i].marks[j];
            avg[i] = sum / 5;
        }
        cout << avg[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        if (avg[i] > avg[i + 1]) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    //вывод упорядоченного
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i].fullname << " ";
        //cout << arr[i].gnumber << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы сравниваете данные из массива avg, который судя по тому, что я понял соответствует массиву arr, но после сравнения делаете swap только массива arr. попробуйте делать swap как элементов массива arr, так и avg